# Save contents of multiple php arrays to same line in file

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 php arrays, `$array1` and `$array2`, how do I print only the contents of the array on the same line tab separated?

INPUT:

```
Array (
  [0] => "100"
  [1] => "98"
  [2] => "95"
)

Array (
  [0] => "http://google.com"
  [1] => "http://facebook.com"
  [2] => "http://yahoo.com"
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
http://google.com       100
http://facebook.com     98
http://yahoo.com        95
```

I tried: `file_put_contents('output.txt', $array1, "\t", $array2 );`but function can only take 2 parameters!  Is there a easy workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, cycle over the elements and concatenate your strings:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    file_put_contents('output.txt', $array1[$i]."\t".$array2[$i], FILE_APPEND );
}
```

Although `file_put_contents` will work as above, I'd implement it with [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [`fclose`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php):

```
$fp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
if ($fp) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        fwrite($fp, $array1[$i]."\t".$array2[$i] );
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

it will be more efficient, because the file is only opened once. It also gives you the flexibility to write the data however you want.

Comment: this only prints out the last item in both array1 and array2

Answer (score 2):

Try with `array_combine` like

```
$new_array = array_combine($array2 , $array1);
file_put_contents('output.txt', $new_array);
```

Comment: Change `array` places  with `$array2 , $array1`

Comment: This will give an error converting array to string and will unhelpfull stuff the string "Array" in your file

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the arrays and save them in a readable format.

```
$saveArray = json_encode(array_combine($arr1 , $arr2));
file_put_contents('array.txt', $saveArray);
```

And to get the array back

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.txt', true));
```

If you want to save the array in a readable format, you can try this

```
$saveArray = print_r(array_combine($arr1 , $arr2), true);
file_put_contents('array.txt', $saveArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your output example is nicely formatted and tabs are notoriously unpredictable depending on what application you are using to view the file you may consider padding the string with spaces:

```
$out = '';
$max = max(array_map('strlen', $arr2))+5;

foreach(array_combine($arr2, $arr1) as $key => $val){
    $out .= sprintf("%-{$max}s%s\n", $key, $val);
}

file_put_contents('output.txt', $out);
```

[example](http://ideone.com/W1iNF1)